# Is it possible to mine specific transaction on Ethereum

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity

I've recently got interested in programming dapps on Ethereum and first question was if it is possible to place a transaction with 0 gwei or 0.1 (as I can see 0 is not possible in MetaMask) and just run special miner that will mine your transaction (or a special contract) only.
I've tried to look it up on internet and I see many talks on reddit about "channeled" transactions but I never see that it actually went anywhere or someone came and said that it is impossible. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're running on the main blockchain, it's possible, but not likely. You can write your own miner that uses whatever criteria you want to decide which transactions to process. Your mined block still needs to become part of the consensus, though, which makes the chances of success much lower (unless you build your own powerful farm of mining rigs).

The alternative is to use a private network. If you run your own private blockchain, you can process transactions for free.

Comment: a question regarding the "chances of success" .. say i have a stuck transaction right now and a nvidia gtx1070 ... can i mine this transaction? How long will it take me realistically? @Adam Kipnis

Comment: @Gewure Highly unlikely. You'd have to have a custom client to give your specific transaction priority AND manage to have your mined transaction be accepted as consensus on the chain. Your one GPU system is competing against farms of mining rigs. You're better off resubmitting your transaction (with the same nonce) and paying a higher price.

Comment: How does it work with gas fees?  Seems miners want to mine the highest gas fees, can I just choose to mine all the low set gas fees?

Comment: @Baddack - Yes, you can set up a miner that accepts 0 wei gas price transactions if you want. You're still competing against other miners to have your block accepted into the chain though.